# Can I say "glad to be treated normally" to express my gratitude?

Tags: expressions

Someone writes back to me, consoling me that everyone has low-emotion periods and there's nothing wrong about that. 
I feel quite relieved since she doesn't show excessive worry or view me as someone weird. But shall I express this feeling by using "Glad to be treated normally"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in saying, "Glad to be treated normally" if that is how you feel. Don't over-think it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to depart from the other diagnosticians and suggest that you "overthink" this a bit.  Or perhaps just think it over.

There's a slight difference between *normal* as applied to you and as applied to others' treatment of you.

Perhaps you mean

> Glad to be treated **as normal**.

Which means that you're happy that others are not treating you as abnormal, i.e., as sick or (as you say) weird.

But

> treated **normally**

can also mean treated in the usual or appropriate manner, and that can be applicable to whatever condition you're in.  If you're suffering from mild, situational depression that afflicts everyone from time to time, then "normally" would be slight concern.  If you're suffering from involutional melancholia, then "normally" would be checking you into a hospital.

Comment: +1 This is what I had in mind, but my answer was poorly worded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think maybe that's why I feel somewhat strange to use "be treated normally"

Answer (score 1):

If they were good to you and treated you like you're a [normal person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_(behavior)), instead of [judging](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judge) you or [upsetting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upset) you, then it's a valid response.

> "Glad to be treated normally"

I'm assuming that normally you are treated in a way that you appreciate.

A better phrase would be (as [@deadrat answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/325681/50044))

> "Glad to be treated as normal"

Comment: Yes, I mean "not judging or upsetting".  Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, you're feeling emotionally down and someone honestly and genuinely consoles you without much drama or patronizing & preaching. So, yes, that does qualify as treating you "normally" and I agree with @Mark Hubbard and @NVZ that you should probably go ahead and say it without overthinking. Probably that's an apt response too - being honest and genuine in return while expressing gratitude.
Except that overthinking can become an uninvited but sticky guest in emotional lows. Been there, done that.

So, if you are feeling awkward to be so direct in your response, you can probably sugarcoat it, by saying something like,

> "thank you for what I see as honest and genuine concern".